# AFNetworking 3.0 GET/POST set acceptableContentTypes and clear cache for images

Tags: ios, image, caching, video, afnetworking-3

I'm using AFNetworking in my project as network layer.
For images I had some problems related to the caching and I updated the framework to 3.0 version.

During the update process I have some problems with requests which fetch the media content (images and videos).

This is my class :

```
+ (void)requestWithMethod:(NSString*)methodTypeValue path:(NSString*)pathValue parameters:(NSDictionary *)params token:(NSString*)token debug:(BOOL)debug completionHandler:(void (^)(id result, NSError *error))block {
    if(debug){
        NSLog(@"Method Type  = %@ \n",methodTypeValue);
        NSLog(@"Link = %@ \n",pathValue);
        NSLog(@"Token = %@", token);
    }

    NSString *linkRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",GatewayRoot,pathValue];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:methodTypeValue URLString:linkRequest parameters:nil error:nil];

    [req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    if (token) {
       [req setValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"AccessToken"];
    }

    [[manager dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
                if (debug) {
                    NSLog(@"response:\n %@ \n",responseObject);
                }
            block(responseObject,nil);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@, %@", error, response, responseObject);
            block(nil, error);
        }
    }] resume];
}
```

I made test and everything is fine related to the normal requests.
I have to fetch some images and videos from server and I receive this error :

> NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: image/png 
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: video/mp4

I tried to set the content types in this ways :

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"image/jpeg",@"video/mpeg",...nil];

manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes =[manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"image/jpeg",@"video/mpeg",...nil];
```

1. Please, can you help my how to set the acceptable content types ?
2. I have other problem related to image caching: with old version I loged in and I fetch the user profile image and after I loged out and relogin with other credentials I received the same image for user profile (I found that it was an issue realted to AFNetworking caching images).

Can you help me with the clear cache request flow ?

Thank a lot for your help !

Comment: Unrelated to your question, if you use `AFJSONRequestSerializer`, I don't believe you need to set the `Content-Type` yourself. I believe AFNetworking does that for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than setting the acceptable content types yourself, you probably just want to specify the appropriate `responseSerializer`. For example, if you want the `UIImage`, you can do:

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
```

If you want the `NSData`, you can do:

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

If you don't want your request to be cached, you should set the `req.cachePolicy` to `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData` or implement `AFURLSessionManager` cache response block, `setDataTaskWillCacheResponseBlock`. Or, of course, you could change your server so that those resources that shouldn't be cached have their header fields set accordingly.

Comment: Thank a lot for your help !  I made the changes and now everything is fine.